# Использование QList<QObjectDerived*> как модель

Tags: c++, qt, qml, qtquick

Есть класс, производный от `QObject`.

```
class MyClass : public QObject
{
    Q_PROPERTY(int a READ...)
}
```

Если объекты этого класса складывать в список `QList<QObject*>`, то они подхватываются в QML и отображаются в `ListView`. А если использовать `QList<MyClass*>`, то `ListView` оказывается пустым. Но хотелось бы в c++-коде использовать именно `QList<MyClass*>`, а лучше `QList<QSharedPointer<MyClass>>`, так как в противном случае придётся использовать восходящее приведение типов, что может привести к ошибкам. Какие есть способы такое провернуть?

Comment: Если я правильно понял вопрос, посмотрите в сторону QQmlListProperty

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Унаследуйтесь от QAbstractListModel, реализуйте методы data, сount и roles и т.д этого класса и наследник засуньте в макрос QML_DECLARE_TYPE()

Итого сможете использовать в QML как объект

```
class MyModel: public QAbstractListModel
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
       QVariant data(const QModelIndex &index, int role = Qt::DisplayRole) const;
       int rowCount(const QModelIndex &parent) const;
       QHash<int,QByteArray> roleNames() const;
   private:
       QList<MyCustomClass*> mList;

};

QML_DECLARE_TYPE(MyModel)
```

Comment: Да, это рабочий вариант. В документации и в интернете гораздо более обширно освещено использование в качестве модели списков и внутренних моделей QML (ListModel), нежели QAbstractItemModel. Не могли бы вы пояснить преимущества использования QAbstractItemModel по сравнению со списками?

Comment: @maestro преимущество в том, что QAbstractItemModel реализуется на С++